# C++ Memory Leak char *

Tags: c++

So I have the class:

```
class Worker{
private:
   char *workerName;
   string SSN;
public:
   Worker();
   Worker(char *, string);
   ~Worker();
   void setWorkerName(char *);
   void setSSN();
   char *getWorkerName();
   string getSSN();
   virtual void printValues();
}
```

so I created a class in my test function:

```
int main(void){
   Worker Person("Person", "555-55-5555");
   //call print member function
   return 0;
}
```

(I also have a deprecated conversion from string constant to char * here, not sure why)

and my constructor for worker is:

```
Worker::Worker(){
   workerName = new char [40];
   SSN = " ";
}

Worker::Worker(char * name, string SSN){
   workerName = new char [40];
   strcpy(workerName, name);
   this->SSN = SSN;
}

Worker::~Worker(){
   delete[] workerName;
}
```

As I type this I now realize that it may be that I don't have my second constructor allocating memory for char *. If that's the issue, how would I go about that?

Comment: It's a deprecated conversion because modifying string literals is undefined behaviour. There's absolutely no reason to use `char *` to point to them. Anyway, you're not following the rule of three. Both can be solved by using `std::string`.

Comment: I have to use char * for this assignment. What's the rule of three?

Comment: Why are you using `char*` *right next* to a use of `string`? Use one or the other (by which I mean, stick to `std::string`) but not both.

Comment: @meagar I wish it were that simple but that's how my professor wants us to do this assignment. I think it's ridiculous, but I'm not the only one, apparently.

Comment: @WorldDominator, Well, at least convince them to make it `const char *` if you're using it to point to string literals. Not having a `const` there is just asking for bugs (and compiler warnings). If you need to modify it, you simply can't make it point to a string literal.

Comment: After editing the wrong answer to add my "amendment" (and is that even the right word for that), I'm going to see if large quantities of strong coffee can help.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm going to email the professor and see what he thinks about the warning. I realize this can lead to potentially bad things but in the end, this project just needs to print the stored values in the classes I'm creating. Don't worry over this one lol

Answer (score 0):

Right now, since you always do `delete[] workerName` in destructor, you'll be attempting to delete a statically allocated string when you call `Person("Person", "555-55-5555");` which does not make sense.

You should keep things consistent.
I suggest you allocate memory and copy over the input string into workerName in your second constructor.

Comment: I must have a destructor for this assignment (in the specifications). Is there any other way to initialize my constructor using Worker(char*, string) ?

Comment: @WorldDominator you can copy the supplied c-string into a newly allocated buffer, but you'd still have problems with the implicitly-defined copy constructor and assignment operator

Comment: @WorldDominator Specifically, if an object were copy constructed or assigned using the compiler-provided default functions, they would both think they owned data pointed to by `workerName`  When the second destructor is called, it will attempt to release memory that has already been released., which will crash the program.

Comment: @bcrist I changed my constructor. Are you basically saying my destructor needs to be empty?

Answer (score 0):

The rule of 3 states that if you need a destructor or a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator, then most likely you need all three.

For example in order to handle *copying* correctly.

Since you are constrained to use `char` pointers (hopefully `char const*` is allowed?), the best you can do is to create a wrapper object for a string value represented by such a pointer, where the wrapper object takes care of handling logical copying correctly. Then use that wrapper object instead of raw pointers. This is generally good C++ practice, except that for strings one would instead use, well, strings. :-)

---

**Amendment**: given the comments about what your (apparently not so good) professor allows, do ask him if the following would be acceptable:

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::swap
#include <string.h>     // ::strcpy, ::strlen

namespace my {
    auto duplicate( char const* const s )
        -> char const*
    { return ::strcpy( new char[strlen( s ) + 1], s ); }

    class String_value
    {
    private:
        char const*     chars_;

    public:
        auto pointer() const
            -> char const*
        { return chars_; }

        void swap_with( String_value& other ) throw()
        { std::swap( chars_, other.chars_ ); }

        void operator=( String_value other )
        { swap_with( other ); }

        ~String_value()
        { delete[] chars_; }

        String_value( char const* const s )
            : chars_( duplicate( s ) )
        {}

        String_value( String_value const& other )
            : chars_( duplicate( other.chars_ ) )
        {}
    };
}  // namespace my

class Worker
{
private:
    my::String_value    name_;
    my::String_value    ssn_;

public:
    auto name() const
        -> char const*
    { return name_.pointer(); }

    auto ssn() const
        -> char const*
    { return ssn_.pointer(); }

    Worker( char const name[], char const ssn[] )
        : name_( name )
        , ssn_( ssn )
    {}
};

#include <ostream>

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& stream, Worker const& w )
{
    return stream << "Worker(" << w.name() << ", " << w.ssn() << ")";
}

#include <iostream>
auto main()
    -> int
{
    using namespace std;
    Worker const person( "Person", "555-55-5555" );
    cout << person << endl;
}
```

Comment: I included the rest of the header file functions. Does this happen to change things for me? I'm not sure if using set/get functions will help me with my constructor issue, I'm guessing not. I'm pretty sure I have to tackle this problem in this manner though or I will lose points. Thanks for explaining the rule of 3 to me though.

Comment: I have it "operational". I just have one question related to this problem left. If I have an inherited class from the class I mentioned above, how can I print the private values of the Worker class in the derived class? I believe that I can't but I need to for the problem I'm working on. I created a constructor in this subclass that assigns the private values of the base class Worker but I don't know how to access them in the derived class to print their values. Thanks!

Comment: The short answer is you can't. The base class must offer the relevant functionality. But that functionality can be `protected`: available to derived classes but not public. * * * Longer answer is that there's always a loophole in C++, but each one with its own dangers and complexity, so just don't. :-)

Comment: Well for my assignment, I declared a derived class PayWorker(char *, string, int, double) with that constructor that has the same char *, string as the base class. He told us to declare the printValues() function as virtual, but how would I print the char *, string without changing them to protected variables in the base class? I redefined the printValues() function in the derived class but I need a method of printing the private char * and string in the PayWorker class.

Comment: Justr let the base class provide access to the requisite information, like the `name` and `ssn` member functions in the code above.

Comment: Oh wow, I just needed to use my previous get statements. Silly me. I'm thinking it would be a lot more sophisticated than that! Lol. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should just use `std::string` for all your strings. That will take care of your memory problems (for now, at least).
2. Your two-parameter constructor is broken. When you want to pass a string parameter into a function, you should use `const string&` instead of `string`. The latter makes a temporary copy of the string you don't need. Since `string` has a constructor that takes `const char*`, you can pass in C strings, too. (There may be a C++11 optimization to be had by using `const string&&` but I forget.)
3. When returning strings verbatim, you should return `const string&` as well, to refrain from making an unnecessary copy. The only time to return a `string` is when you are returning a temporary (e.g. the `string` class's binary `+` operation is declared  `string operator +(const string&)` because the returned string is neither the left-hand or right-hand string, but a new string).
4. By using `string`s for storage, you don't need a destructor since the `string` releases storage when destroyed.
5. You can mark methods that don't change the object as `const` after the parameter list. This makes `this` into a `const Worker*`. Methods which are not marked `const` this way cannot be used on `const Worker` objects.
6. Define the simple methods right in the class. This lets the compiler easily inline them.

Then your code looks like:

```
class Worker {
private:
   string workerName;
   string SSN;
public:
   Worker() {}
   Worker(const string& workerName_, const string& SSN_)
   : workerName(workerName_), SSN(SSN_) {}
   void setWorkerName(const string& newName) { workerName = newName; }
   void setSSN(const string& newSSN) { SSN = newSSN; }
   const string& getWorkerName() const { return workerName; }
   const string& getSSN() const { return SSN; }
   virtual void printValues() const;
};

int main(void) {
   Worker Person("Person", "555-55-5555");
   Person.printValues();
   return 0;
}

void Worker::printValues() const {
    cout << "Name: " << workerName << ", SSN: " << SSN << endl;
}
```

---

Okay, so your professor wants you to use `char*` and manage things by hand. Whatever. Now you need that destructor, and the copy constructor, and assignment. Know what? Let's blow his mind and *prevent* copies just because.

In C++, string literals are `const char*` and *not* `char*`, so if your prof is expecting `char*` you *will* get compiler warnings. If he marks you wrong for being [const correct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness), take it up with his boss because the prof is incompetent and is teaching practices that will cause problems in the real world.

So let's go through the code again, transforming the `string` version into the `char*` version. First the class. Because anything that *sets* a string is nontrivial, most of our inlined methods aren't inline any more:

```
class Worker {
private:
   char *workerName;
   char *SSN;
   Worker(const Worker&);
   Worker& operator=(const Worker&);
public:
   Worker();
   Worker(const char *workerName_, const char *SSN_);
   ~Worker();
   void setWorkerName(const char *newName);
   void setSSN(const char *newSSN);
   const char *getWorkerName() const { return workerName; }
   const char *getSSN() const { return SSN; }
   virtual void printValues() const;
};
```

Note the added copy constructor and equals operator marked private, in addition to the public destructor. This prevents `Worker` from being copied, since nobody can call them. (This is the "rule of three" Cheers was talking about.)

Now your default constructor. You have:

```
Worker::Worker(){
   workerName = new char [40];
   SSN = " ";
}
```

The problems here are that you're setting `workerName` to point to newly-allocated, (IIRC) zeroed memory, and that you're pointing SSN at a string constant. You should be allocating memory for both, and that memory should be just big enough to hold the value. This means allocating two arrays of one char, whose value is `'\0'` (i.e. a string that's just a null terminator):

```
Worker::Worker(){
   workerName = new char [1];
   workerName[0] = '\0';
   SSN = new char [1];
   SSN[0] = '\0';
}
```

You can also do it with C++ initializer syntax:

```
Worker::Worker(): workerName(new char [1]), SSN(new char [1]) {
   workerName[0] = '\0';
   SSN[0] = '\0';
}
```

Next, your two-parameter constructor. Same thing here, except you use `strlen` to find the length of the strings and `strcpy` to copy them:

```
Worker::Worker(const char *workerName_, const char *SSN_) {
   workerName = new char [strlen(workerName_) + 1];
   strcpy(workerName, workerName_);
   SSN = new char [strlen(SSN_) + 1];
   strcpy(SSN, SSN_));
}
```

Note the array size is "length plus one" because `strlen` doesn't count the `'\0'` at the end.

Also note that if you were using `malloc` and `free` like you're supposed to with C strings, you could just use C's `strdup` function:

```
Worker::Worker(const char *workerName_, const char *SSN_)
: workerName(strdup(workerName_)), SSN(strdup(SSN_)) {
}
```

But you shouldn't free `malloc`'d memory with `delete[]` and you shouldn't free `new[]` memory with `free`.

The destructor was actually fine, just have to add the like for the SSN:

```
Worker::~Worker(){
   delete[] workerName;
   delete[] SSN;
}
```

I'll leave the "set" functions as an exercise for the reader. Just remember that they need to 1) delete the existing value, and 2) allocate the new one. Same procedures as above.

Now if your prof dictated that `workerName` be `char*` and `SSN` be `string`... well, mixing the above code to do that is another exercise for the reader.